# Argparse arguments from file and string CLI arguments both

Tags: python, argparse

I want to launch my script like this:

```
python3 main.py @params.conf 1 2
```

where `params.conf` is a file and `1`, `2` are string arguments.

I know how to parse file alone:

```
argparser = ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('arg1', help='heeelp') 
...
args = argparser.parse_args()
```

But how to parse following arguments?

Comment: [The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) explain how to parse positional arguments generally, have you tried something? What happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An argument prefixed with `@` is treated as if its contents were in the command line directly, one argument per line. So if the contents of `params.conf`is

```
2
3
```

And you define a parser like

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
p.add_argument("a")
p.add_argument("b")
p.add_argument("c")
p.add_argument("d")
args = p.parse_args()
```

and you call your script as

```
script.py 1 @params.conf 4
```

then your arguments `a` through `d` will be set to 1 through 4, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You just add more `argparser.add_argument` calls.

Like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('arg1', type=str)
parser.add_argument('arg2', type=str)
parser.add_argument('arg3', type=str)

args = parser.parse_args() 

print(args)  # arguments are parsed
```